# React Routing among static and dynamic path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, dynamic-routing

here is my code, but it always skip the "/products/:qfpp" and routes to "/:makeName/:modelName".
I have no idea how to fix it, so, would you please help me regarding that.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import ProductList from './Components/ProductList';
import ModelList from './Components/ModelList'
import CategoryList from './Components/CategoryList';
import ProductDetail from './Components/ProductDetail';


class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <div>
      <Header />
       <Switch>
        <Route path="/:makeName" exact render={(props)=><ModelList url= 
  {props.match.params.makeName} />}/>

        <Route path="/:makeName/:modelName" exact render={(props)=> 
          <CategoryList makeName={props.match.params.makeName}                                                                           
          modelName={props.match.params.modelName}/>}/>

        <Route path="/:makeName/:modelName/:catName" exact render={(props)=> 
          <ProductList makeName={props.match.params.makeName}                                                                                        
          modelName={props.match.params.modelName}                                                                                         
          catName={props.match.params.catName} />}/>

        <Route path="/products/:qfpp" exact render={(props) => 
          <ProductDetail url={props.match.params.qfpp}/>}/>

        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </div>
   );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the exact property

Answer (score 0):

What version of react router do you have? Did you check your components for this routes, maybe this components are causing problems. You can check your app with divs instead of components here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h7kwp2

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"

Comment: The components works with the routes with no issue, and if I comment the lines for the first three routes, the last one gets the route correctly. the issue happens only when all routes are there, it ignores the last one.

Answer (score 0):

In that case it's normal, if your router see the route `/products/my-id` it can be resolve by `/:makeName/:modelName`:

- `products` = `:makeName`
- `my-id` = `:modelName`

You have to declare the route `/products/:qfpp` before, then the router will used the route `/products/:qfpp` insted of `/:makeName/:modelName`

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/products/:qfpp"/>
    <Route path="/:makeName/:modelName"/>
</Switch>
```